# applying css to javascript document.writeln ( )

Tags: javascript, css

```
var width = prompt("How many x's would you like in the bottom row? 1-100 is good)", "50")
var a_line= "";
var loop = 0;

while (loop < width) {
    a_line = a_line + "x";
    loop = loop + 1;
    document.writeln(a_line + "<br>");
}
```

This makes 1 x print on the first line 2 x's on the 2nd line and so on up to the number of x's the user gives.

How do I apply styling to the result of `document.writeln(a_line + "<br>")`? i.e centering each line.

Comment: document.writeln("<p align='center'>"+ a_line + "</p>");. Inline css should work

Comment: Dude, use jQuery :) you are going to save yourself like 3,000,000 hours (in jQury that statement is $(".element_to_append_to").append($("<p>").css("attribute","value").html("P Tag Content"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get CSS applied to using the correct way to insert html into a page, which is by not using document.writeln, but by picking the element where the content has to be placed in based on an id or css selector:

- document.getElementById('...').innerHTML = "<p class='css-class'>...</p>";
- document.querySelector('...').innerHTML = "<p class='css-class'>...</p>";
- element selection using MooTools/jQuery/etc and then setting the content.

JavaScript's document.writeln does not print HTML, but prints plain text content, so it will never be interpreted by the browser. Build your string, then inject it into the element you want with an .innerHTML (plain JavaScript) or .html() (in jQuery), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make a_line be contained in a paragraph (`<p> tag`) with some css applied.

```
while (loop < width) {
 a_line += "x";
 b_line = "<p style='text-align:center;width:100%;'>" + a_line + "</p>";
 loop = loop + 1;
 document.writeln(b_line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<div style='..........'">");
while( loop < width) { .....}
document.write("</div>");
```

Something like that. Although really you should avoid using `document.write`.

Comment: why do you recommend avoiding document.write and what would you use here optimally?

Comment: I would use `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(a_line));` - That's the compact version. A less compact one could apply styles to the `div` and events such as `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the HTML to the x's inside the string like so:

```
var width = +prompt("How many x's would you like in the bottom row? 1-100 is good)", "50"),
    a_line = "",
    loop = 0;

while (loop < width) {
    a_line += "x";
    loop += 1;
    document.writeln('<center>' + a_line + '</center><br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `document.write/ln` to modify a webpage.  Pages are displayed based on the [Document Object Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html), which is a tree of elements, not plain text.  You should create an element for each line, give each the necessary text content and add to the document:

```
var width = prompt("How many x's would you like in the bottom row? 1-100 is good)", "50"),
    a_line = "",
    loop = 0,
    element;

while (loop < width) {
    a_line = a_line + "x";
    loop = loop + 1;
    element = document.createElement("div");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a_line));
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

CSS:

```
div {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hQHHu/