# CSS in javascript document.writeln ( ) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with an app front-end develop and facing a styling problem when I tried to make the front looks good. I have the following code:

Out put with HTML and CSS(include inline CSS and style sheet): this looks perfect but don't have the data, like title, startDate etc. is hard coded.

```
<div class="rsvpEvent">                     
    <p style="text-align:center;"><b>title</b></p><p class="cancel">cancel</p>
    <div style="width:30%;height:68%;float:left;margin-left:2%;margin-right:2%;">
        <img class="backgroundImage" src="img/surf2.jpg">                       
    </div>
    <b style="color:#3ad7ff">3 friends <font face="ico" color="#ffffff">&#xe60a;</font> 9 others</b><br />
    startDate<b style="color:#3ad7ff;">15km</b>
    <div class="facebookBox"><font face="ico" style="position:relative;top:-6vh;left:1vw;">&#xe608;</font></div>
    <div class="twitterBox"><font face="ico" style="position:relative;top:-1vh;left:1vw;">&#xe609;</font></div>
    <img src="img/Tulips.jpg" class="profileBox" onclick="showProfilefromRSVP()">
    <div class="viewBox" onclick="showFeed()">view</div>
</div>
```

Then, I turned it into javascript with writeln, it does have the data like title, startDate etc. but all the styling include inline styling and style sheet are not working.

```
xhr.onload=function(){
    result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    for(var i=0;i<result[0].length;i++){
        var title = result[0][i];
        var startDate = result[1][i];

        document.writeln("<div class=\"rsvpEvent\">");
        document.writeln("<p style=\"text-align:center;\"><b>"+title+"</b></p><p class=\"cancel\">cancel</p>");
        document.writeln("<div style=\"width:30%;height:68%;float:left;margin-left:2%;margin-right:2%;\">");
        document.writeln("<img class=\"backgroundImage\" src=\"img/surf2.jpg\">");
        document.writeln("</div>");
        document.writeln("<b style=\"color:#3ad7ff\">3 friends <font face=\"ico\" color=\"#ffffff\">&#xe60a;</font> 9 others</b><br />");
        document.writeln(startDate+"<b style=\"color:#3ad7ff;\">15km</b>");
        document.writeln("<div class=\"facebookBox\"><font face=\"ico\" style=\"position:relative;top:-6vh;left:1vw;\">&#xe608;</font></div>");
        document.writeln("<div class=\"twitterBox\"><font face=\"ico\" style=\"position:relative;top:-1vh;left:1vw;\">&#xe609;</font></div>");
        document.writeln("<img src=\"img/Tulips.jpg\" class=\"profileBox\" onclick=\"showProfilefromRSVP()\">");
        document.writeln("<div class=\"viewBox\" onclick=\"showFeed()\">view</div>");
        document.writeln("</div>");
    }
}
```

Any help on this? Many thanks!

Comment: What's the final result that's written (`document.body.innerHtml`)?

Comment: Why are you using document.write? That is a bad practice!

Comment: `document.writeln` in an onload handler, it's never going to work ...

Comment: The answer here should apply for this question, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996043/applying-css-to-javascript-document-writeln

Comment: Also font tag has been obsolete for ages.

Comment: @epascarello Everyone who post question here because they don't know or they stuck, but we all have desire to learn. If you can show me how you think to make it work, please advise me instead of saying how bad my code is. I am fresh graduated student, and I know my code is bad and it's not working, that's why I am asking.

Comment: @DukeWang Did you not see my answer below? I explained your problem and gave you a solution. Beginner tutorials that use `document.write` would be banned because it leads to issues like this that you are facing.

Comment: @epascarello just saw it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use document.write after the page load, it is like using a whiteboard, it erases the board so you start fresh. So all of the code that was there was removed. You want to use DOM methods to add new content. So you want to use either [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var content = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++) {
        var title = result[0][i];
        var startDate = result[1][i];
        content.push("<div class=\"rsvpEvent\">");
        content.push("<p style=\"text-align:center;\"><b>" + title + "</b></p><p class=\"cancel\">cancel</p>");
        content.push("<div style=\"width:30%;height:68%;float:left;margin-left:2%;margin-right:2%;\">");
        content.push("<img class=\"backgroundImage\" src=\"img/surf2.jpg\">");
        content.push("</div>");
        content.push("<b style=\"color:#3ad7ff\">3 friends <font face=\"ico\" color=\"#ffffff\">&#xe60a;</font> 9 others</b><br />");
        content.push(startDate + "<b style=\"color:#3ad7ff;\">15km</b>");
        content.push("<div class=\"facebookBox\"><font face=\"ico\" style=\"position:relative;top:-6vh;left:1vw;\">&#xe608;</font></div>");
        content.push("<div class=\"twitterBox\"><font face=\"ico\" style=\"position:relative;top:-1vh;left:1vw;\">&#xe609;</font></div>");
        content.push("<img src=\"img/Tulips.jpg\" class=\"profileBox\" onclick=\"showProfilefromRSVP()\">");
        content.push("<div class=\"viewBox\" onclick=\"showFeed()\">view</div>");
        content.push("</div>");
    }
    document.getElementById("outputElem").innerHTML = content.join("");
}
```

Comment: Can I do document.getElementByClassName("outputElem") instead of getElementById?

Comment: Where there is no getElementByClassName, there is `getElementsByClassName` which returns a node set so it would be `document.getElementsByClassName("outputElemClass")[0].innerHTML = content.join("");`

Comment: I kept your code and tested it. I have 4 data in db which should bring me 4 content, but first 3 only did a flash and left me the 4th one only. Do I need any additional code?

Comment: Ah, append outside the loop! Missed the loop.

Comment: Have done that before you update :) Still appreciate for your update!